# Acces denied to registry on windows 8 for vb.net app

Tags: windows, vb.net, registry

I created a small app in vb.net for a friend. The problem is that on my PC (W7 64bits) it works great (registry reading / writing) but on my friends PC (W8 64bits) it doesn't work. 
It it strange but at the moment he runs my app (it checks the registry on loading) it gives him a "Access to registry denied" error. I tried to run it with admin rights but it doesn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
 Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1
    Dim planned As Date

    Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub planifier_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles planifier_button.Click
        Dim toExecute As String = String.Format("shutdown -s -f -t {0}", 100)

        Dim currentDate = System.DateTime.Now
        Dim futureDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
        Dim difference = futureDate - currentDate

        Console.Out.WriteLine(difference)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -f -t " & Math.Round(difference.TotalSeconds))
        Me.planned = futureDate
        saveStgFile(futureDate)
        setup()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Shutdown_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Console.Out.WriteLine(Application.ProductName & " & " & Application.ExecutablePath)

        getStgFile()
        getPlanned()

        setup()

        Dim baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
        Startup.Checked = baseKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).GetValue(Application.ProductName).Equals(Application.ExecutablePath)
    End Sub
    Private Sub cancel_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cancel_button.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "-a")
        Me.planned = Nothing
        saveStgFile(Nothing)
        setup()
    End Sub
    Sub setup()
        If Me.planned.Equals(Nothing) Then
            cancel_button.Enabled = False
            planifier_button.Enabled = True
            planifier_button.Text = "Planifier"
        Else
            cancel_button.Enabled = True
            planifier_button.Enabled = False
            planifier_button.Text = Me.planned.TimeOfDay.ToString()
        End If
    End Sub

    Function getPlanned() As TimeSpan
        Dim stg As String = getStgFile()
        Dim fileContent As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(stg)
        Dim timespan As Date
        If fileContent = "none" Then
            Me.planned = Nothing
        ElseIf Date.TryParse(fileContent, timespan) Then
            Me.planned = timespan
        End If

        Return (Me.planned - System.DateTime.Now)
    End Function
    Function getStgFile() As String
        Dim stgFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "AutoShutdown")

        If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(stgFile) = False Then
            FileSystem.MkDir(stgFile)
        End If

        stgFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(stgFile, "settings.ini")
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(stgFile) = False Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(stgFile, "none", False)
        End If

        Return stgFile
    End Function
    Sub saveStgFile(planned As Date)
        Dim stgFile As String = getStgFile()
        Try
            If (planned.Equals(Nothing)) Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(stgFile, "none", False)
            Else
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(stgFile, planned.ToString(), False)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Startup_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Startup.CheckedChanged
        Dim baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
        If Startup.Checked Then
            baseKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath)
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Add to startup")
        Else
            baseKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).DeleteValue(Application.ProductName)
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Remove from startup")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your friend does not have the necessary privileges to access the registry. This usually requires Administrator privileges. He needs to run the app with a user profile that has the necessary permissions to the registry..

Comment: hmm i'm pretty sure he has the rights because he can install anything on his computer with his user account, and other softwares using the registry don't give this error message

Comment: oh ! i also just remembered that it told him to use the "Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration" to repair the pb